# Server detected IP address of some clients as a shared address (cannot detect public ip address of some clients)

Tags: networking, ip, iis, ip-address, windows-server

I renting a small server from a local provider and deployed a small website on it via IIS.

After sometime looking at the IIS Logs. I found that my server detected wrong IP address of some clients request to it. For example , one of my client have IP address : 118.71.163.19 when connect to other servers or checking on Whatismyip's website but when they sent request to my server, the IIS logged his IP address as 100.89.220.91.  I already asked on serverfault, and got some suggestions that this issue related to network and should be asked on SuperUser:

> - The 118.71.163.19 is probably the correct public client address because 100.89.220.91 is not a public address, it is a Shared address (100.64.0.0/10) that is assigned by the ISP for CGN, and it internal to the ISP, which assigns a public address at the NAT point in the ISP
> - That means you have a residential network connection, and you should be asking on Super User.

What should I can do to fix this issue? Should I contact the server's provider and tell them that they are using residential network connection? I'm just a junior web developer and not good at network. I just want my server able to correct logging the IP address for anti-spamming and GEO IP to redirect the users on my website to foreigner section.